# How to adjust for humidity when making rice?

Tags: rice, sushi

Years ago, I ate at Sushi Yasuda in New York. After I went, I was reading up on the chef, and an article about him mentioned that he accounted for air humidity while making his sushi rice. Wow! My kind of guy!

There is a 'how much water with your rice' conversation on this site, one that basically said "get a great Zojirushi," but I'd like to hear from an expert sushi rice cooker -- can anyone explain to me a formula or set of considerations for making really great sushi rice? I'm thinking of the sort of thing taught sushi chefs at the Japanese equivalent of the CIA, if there is such a thing.

Here is a link mentioning ambient humidity as a concern for rice cooking: http://www.mail-archive.com/ugandanet@kym.net/msg13272.html

Comment: I'm not an expert sushi rice cooker, but the humidity inside a rice cooker is already at 100%...I can't imagine how the outside air humidity could have any affect on how rice is cooked.  Altitude, yes.  Humidity, no.

Comment: Unless the chef was talking about rice drying out after it is put on the plate, in which case you would *slightly* increase the water and cooking time for dry climates.

Comment: Analogously in baking, flour changes weight depending on air humidity, so I can conceive of this being a legitimate concern.

Answer (score 3):

Dry rice will have more or less water content dependant on the ambient humidity. If you want to test how much you have to account for this, take some rice during a humid day, weight, dry in a 200F oven for a few hours and then weigh again.